# how to load a create and load a new record into a form in extjs 4.0

Tags: extjs4

I'm using mvc approach and extending the pandora example.

I would like to add a new record to a form. I need to pre-assign some properties.  I have the following handler. Which fills out the form. However when i try and sync it does not post the new info. ie using fire bug i see that it post the records that were previously there. At what stage should i add it to the store.

```
onNewPartSelect: function (selModel, selection) {

    var form = Ext.getCmp('partForm');
    form.getForm().reset();

    var part = new Pandora.model.Part({
        Name: 'my new record'
    });

    form.loadRecord(part);
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For loading a new record into the form:

```
    var iUserForm = this.getUserDetailsForm(),
        iRecord = Ext.create('BS.model.User');

    iUserForm.loadRecord( iRecord );
```

And upon submit:

```
    var iUserForm = this.getUserDetailsForm();

    if (iUserForm.getForm().isValid())
    {
        var iRecord = iUserForm.getForm().getRecord(),
            iValues = iUserForm.getForm().getValues(),

        iRecord.set( iValues );
        this.getUsersStore().insert(0, iRecord);

    }
```